# Select a Office Fabric pivot tab with JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, office-fabric

I'm using the pivot control with Office Fabric. It's the standard JS library, not the React/Angular ones. How can I select a tab with JS/JQuery?

I call API when the page loads and dependent on the result I want to display the first tab or the third.

```html
<div class="ms-Pivot">
  <ul class="ms-Pivot-links">
    <li class="ms-Pivot-link is-selected" data-content="files" title="My files" tabindex="1">
      My files
    </li>
    <li class="ms-Pivot-link " data-content="recent" title="Recent" tabindex="1">
      Recent
    </li>
    <li class="ms-Pivot-link " data-content="shared" title="Shared with me" tabindex="1">
      Shared with me
    </li>
    <li class="ms-Pivot-link" tabindex="1">
      <i class="ms-Pivot-ellipsis ms-Icon ms-Icon--More"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="ms-Pivot-content" data-content="files">
    This is the my files tab.
  </div>
  <div class="ms-Pivot-content" data-content="recent">
    This is the recent tab.
  </div>
  <div class="ms-Pivot-content" data-content="shared">
    This is the shared with me tab.
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var PivotElements = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-Pivot");
  for (var i = 0; i < PivotElements.length; i++) {
    new fabric['Pivot'](PivotElements[i]);
  }
</script>
```

https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/Components/Pivot/Pivot.html

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've not tried anything. I was a bit stumped where to start. They're a bit clunky to use so may be I'm assuming it's a complicated answer.

Comment: I would recommend you include the relevant source code and not just a link to the library documentation. Could you also be more clear by what you mean "select" Which tab should be selected and at what point should it be selected? What is being used to trigger the selection? So far from what you have posted leaves me with nothing but the example/sample source code which give no clue of needing a selector for tabs.

Comment: This is what I currently have which seems to function just fine without the need of `jQuery` to select tabs.... [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4y65Lkj9/)

Comment: *"I call API when the page"* Can you tell me what the response is from the API call that related to which tab should be selected please?

Comment: On page load I call an API to see if the customer exists in another system - if yes then I go to tab 1 if no I go to tab 3